# Split pair of ranges of dates by another pair of ranges in SAS

Tags: sas

I have been working on this and I am not getting my dataset as expected.

I have a SAS dataset 1 given below for sample observations. This table gives the start and end ranges of dates.

```
Dataset 1

id  start         end      var1
A   03/15/1992  03/20/1992  1
A   03/24/1992  03/26/1992  2
A   03/28/1992  03/31/1992  5
B   06/06/1994  06/06/1994  1
```

I have another SAS dataset which gives the outer ends of ranges of dates that should contain start and end ranges from dataset 1.

```
Dataset 2

A   01/01/1992  03/16/1992  3
A   03/17/1992  03/19/1992  4
A   03/20/1992  05/25/1992  6
B   06/06/1994  06/06/1994  8
```

Final table should have the **exact ranges of dataset 1** and dataset 2 ranges should be adjusted so that the end dates are continuous to succeeding and preceding rows. In other words, final table should have non-overlapping intervals.

```
Final expected dataset


A   01/01/1992  03/14/1992  .    3
A   03/15/1992  03/20/1992  1   .    <---- range stays the same as in dataset1
A   03/21/1992  03/23/1992  .    6
A   03/24/1992  03/26/1992  2   .    <---- range stays the same as in dataset1
A   03/27/1992  03/27/1992  .    6
A   03/28/1992  03/31/1992  5   .    <---- range stays the same as in dataset1
A   04/01/1992  05/25/1992  .    6
B   06/06/1994  06/06/1994  1   8
```

I am not sure if this can be achieved in SAS.

**Addition to my earlier post:**  I have another data that need the ranges to be adjusted exactly as above but I don't have the IDs in dataset1 but rather another identifier that is common between the two dataset. Example dataset given below:

```
      Dataset 1
          
          id2   start      end      var1
        A1122 03/15/1992 03/20/1992 1
        A1122 03/24/1992 03/26/1992 2
        A1122 03/21/1992 03/22/1992 2
        A2222 03/25/1994 03/25/1994 1
        A1122 01/01/1992 01/01/1992 1


 Dataset 2
  
id1  id2  start       end     var2
    A A1122 01/01/1992 03/16/1992 3
    A A1122 03/17/1992 03/19/1992 4
    A A2222 03/20/1992 05/25/1992 6
    B A1122 06/06/1994 06/06/1994 8
```

Final dataset must retain all ranges from dataset1 exactly the way it is and ranges in dataset 2 to be adjusted for continuity.

```
Final dataset
   id1  id2  start       end  var1  var2
A A1122 01/01/1992 01/01/1992 1 . <-same as dataset 1
A A1122 01/02/1992 01/14/1992 . 3
A A1122 03/15/1992 03/16/1992 1 2 <-from dataset 1 and 2
A A1122 03/17/1992 03/19/1992 1 4 <-from dataset 1 and 2
A A2222 03/20/1992 03/20/1992 1 6 <-from dataset 1 and 2
A A1122 03/21/1992 03/22/1992 2 . <-same as dataset 1
A A1122 03/23/1992 03/24/1992 . 6
A A2222 03/25/1992 03/25/1992 1 . <-same as dataset 1
B A1122 06/06/1994 06/06/1994 . 8
```

The ranges in dataset1 could completely overlap the ranges in dataset2 and spill to next row or lie within the ranges of dataset2. The ranges in dataset2 have no gaps between rows.

*More explanation:*The final dataset should also retain the 'end' dates of dataset2 so that the corresponding var1 would be correctly associated with the range. To achieve this, ranges in dataset 1 may have to split eg. obs. # 3,4,5 in final dataset.

Answer (score 0):

If your sample data is representable, try this. I assumed the variables names `var1` and `var2` for your last two variables

```
data one;
input id $ (start end)(:mmddyy10.) var1;
format start end mmddyy10.;
datalines;
A 03/15/1992 03/20/1992 1
A 03/24/1992 03/26/1992 2
A 03/28/1992 03/31/1992 5
B 06/06/1994 06/06/1994 1
;

data two;
input id $ (start end)(:mmddyy10.) var1;
format start end mmddyy10.;
datalines;
A 01/01/1992 03/16/1992 3
A 03/17/1992 03/19/1992 4
A 03/20/1992 05/25/1992 6
B 06/06/1994 06/06/1994 8
;

data want (drop=s);
   merge one(keep=start rename=start=s) two(rename=var1=var2);
   end = s - 1;
   var1 = .;
   output;
   set one;
   var2 = .;
   output;
run;
```

Result:

```
id  start       end         var2 var1 
A   01/01/1992  03/14/1992  3    . 
A   03/15/1992  03/20/1992  .    1 
A   03/17/1992  03/23/1992  4    . 
A   03/24/1992  03/26/1992  .    2 
A   03/20/1992  03/27/1992  6    . 
A   03/28/1992  03/31/1992  .    5 
B   06/06/1994  06/05/1994  8    . 
B   06/06/1994  06/06/1994  .    1
```

Comment: Thank you so much draycut!  Such a compact code.  The code I had written was too convoluted.  This works perfectly. In my dataset 'one' I do not have the same number of observations for each ID as those in 'two' for eg. the third observation for 'one' could be  missing for ID 1.

Comment: just made some changes to my original post.  Could you please help me with the code?  Thanks!

Comment: Ok. Given the new data sets, what does your required result look like? The same?

Comment: @daycut.  Just posted the final result.

Comment: I don't understand the logic here. You say "Final dataset must retain all ranges from dataset1 exactly the way it is". But the date range from obs 1 in dataset 1 is not retained? Please explain thorougly how you get the result from the two posted data sets.

Comment: I see that I have not explained it clearly and also the final dataset is not what I need it to be.  I have made the edits and also added extra explanation.  Thanks dracut!